# Jailbroken detection failed with liberty lite

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, security, jailbreak

Recently faced a issue securing iOS Application with [Jailbreak detection](https://cydia-app.com/unc0ver/) on OS 12.1 with [Liberty Lite](https://cydia-app.com/jailbreak-detection/) enabled

I have jailbreak detection in AppDelegate and initial ViewController where I test following

1. File existence for below paths

   - /Applications/Cydia.app
   - /private/var/stash
   - /private/var/stash
   - /private/var/tmr/stash
   - /private/var/lib/cydiar/stash
   - /private/var/mobile/Library/SBr/stash
   - /Library/MobileSubstratr/stash
   - /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibrr/stash
   - /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibrarr/stash
   - /System/Library/LaunchDaemonr/stash
   - /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.sar/stash
   - /var/car/stash
   - /var/lir/stash
   - /var/lir/stash
   - /var/lor/stash
   - /var/tmr/stash
   - /bin/bashr/stash
   - /bin/shr/stash
   - /usr/sr/stash
   - /usr/liber/stash
   - /usr/bir/stash
   - /usr/libexer/stash
   - /etc/ssr/stash
   - /etr/stash
2. I test if application canOpenURL Schema "cydia://package/com.example.package"
3. Write file to stringToWrite.write(toFile:"/private/photos.txt"

Liberty Lite is able to bypass all 3 checks and let run the application on a Jailbroken device, is there any other way I can detect such by passing tweaks(Liberty Lite) and stop the application from running on a Jailbroken device

Comment: did you find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, no.

Any form of jailbreak check can be relatively easily worked around and a motivated user can always make another tweak for whatever check you might be using at the time. Consider it similar to attempts to prevent cracks for different software, it's just a game of whack-a-mole where the developing side is losing.

[I wrote an article about this](https://infinum.com/the-capsized-eight/jailbreaking-bad-why-jailbreak-detection-in-ios-apps-is-pointless) some time ago if you're interested into details of why this can't work.

Comment: Definitely agree to your point, But its developing side job to make as many layers as possible specifically once which are visible to you

Comment: I honestly disagree, jailbreak detection is pointless as a business decision itself, and there's nothing to gain from preventing certain users from using your app.

Considering the nature of the platform and the fact that the physical device is not yours to limit, you don't have the possibility, or even the right to decide what the user does with it.

Comment: You are right if the business is for wide range and to keep adding new number of users, But business case specific at my end is for Internal enterprise within specific users, and most important here is to protect the API and Exposing the domain.

Comment: If your API is not secure from the client side, then it's simply not secure, jailbreaking is not an issue then.

Comment: API has been given green signal from security team but do you have any document which shall enlighten some more info like your brief  article about Jailbroken device

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [library here](https://github.com/avltree9798/isJailbroken). Liberty detection is managed to be detected with the method `isInjectedWithDynamicLibrary()`.

I have personally tested, and it works with my app on iOS 12.1.2 (iPhone 7).

Comment: I think I would have to look into that after a long time spent on it I just gave up since my app was enterprise it needs to have jailbreak condition handled

Comment: @GreenDev come back and comment after you have tested, we are more interested to the result